# How to map a jsonb array of numbers to a jsonb array of strings?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb array of numbers or strings, e.g. `'[1, "2", 3]'::jsonb`

I want to map all values to strings, so that I can end up with `'["1", "2", "3"]'::jsonb`

I tried this:

```
select jsonb_agg(jsonb_array_elements_text('[1, 2, 3]'::jsonb))
```

But it is complaining

```
LINE 1: select jsonb_agg(jsonb_array_elements_text('[1, 2, 3]'::json...
                         ^
HINT:  You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do what the error message suggests: use the set returning function `jsonb_array_elements_text()` like a table:

```
select jsonb_agg(element)
from jsonb_array_elements_text('[1, 2, 3]'::jsonb) as x(element);
```

Comment: thanks it works!  I could tell from my research that the answer was going to look something like this, but I couldn't get the proper incantation.  if you don't mind a follow-up, what is the meaning of the "x()" in your answer?

Comment: It's a [table alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES)